# Background image not filling layout and taking extra space above and below

Tags: java, android, background-image

[image: Linear Layout with white card as background]

The blue bordered part is a `LinearLayout` and the white card part is the background image I have used. The background image is not filling the layout.

I have tried keeping an `ImageView` in a `FrameLayout` and making scale type as centerCrop but even that didn't work. I can use a `CardView` instead but I want this type of shadow as shown in the picture which I couldn't achieve with attributes of `CardView`.

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@drawable/squared_background_shadow">
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe the issue is in the picture you use, it could be png with transparent background?
2. Which special attributes are you using in `LinearLayout`, which don't support by `CardView`?
3. You can try `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

Comment: It could be png, I mean, sometimes there is transparent space in the image, you should check it. I suppose the same color and shadow can be reached with the drawable shape.

Comment: Hi, samaromku! I have tried scaleType but that didn't work and Yes! I am using png and it is having a transparent background. Please tell me whether there is any way to ignore this transparent background in android?

Comment: Could you please share that drawable shape code here? It's very important for me

Comment: Shadow is like this where the bottom is 4px with a blur of 16 and shadow color of #11455B63

Comment: `<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#11455B63" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>`

Comment: Thank you very much samaromku! It worked like a charm.

I just want to know another thing whether can we give blur for a shadow in XML? because it's actually a blurred shadow...